# When finished create user using (CreateUserWizard control) add profile information in the same process

Tags: asp.net, login-control

When I try this code it's give this error message

This property cannot be set for anonymous users.

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Roles.AddUserToRole((sender as CreateUserWizard).UserName, "Admin");

    Control ctrl = CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer;
    TextBox txtAdminAddress= (TextBox)ctrl.FindControl("txtAdminAddress");
    TextBox txtAdminCountry= (TextBox)ctrl.FindControl("txtAdminCountry");
    TextBox txtAdminCity= (TextBox)ctrl.FindControl("txtAdminCity");

    HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetProfileGroup("AdminGroup").SetPropertyValue("AdminAddress", txtAdminAddress.Text);
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetProfileGroup("AdminGroup").SetPropertyValue("AdminCountry", txtAdminCountry.Text);
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetProfileGroup("AdminGroup").SetPropertyValue("AdminCity", txtAdminCity.Text);
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.Save();

}
```

Config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"> 
  <properties> 
    <group name="AdminGroup"> 
      <add name="AdminAddress" type="System.String"/> 
      <add name="AdminCountry" type="System.String"/> 
      <add name="AdminCity" type="System.String"/> 
    </group> 
  </properties> 
  <providers> 
     <clear/> 
     <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="/"/> 
  </providers> 
</profile>
```

Comment: Please show your Profile Properties set in config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the User, You need to fetch the profile of recently created user to start updating values. Since No profile is Loaded, it won't allow to set these values for anonymous users.

```
string strUsername = (sender as CreateUserWizard).UserName;
ProfileCommon p = Profile.GetProfile(strUsername);

//update the field and save
p.AdminAddress= txtAdminAddress.Text;
p.Save();
```

The `ProfileBase` object (provided by the `Page.Profile` property) includes a useful `GetProfile()` function that retrieves, by user name, the profile information for a specific user.

`GetProfile()` returns a `ProfileCommon` object.

[ Note: The profile properties set in Config file doesn't allow setting values for Anonymous users. If you want to allow this for anonymous users also use:

```
<add name="AdminAddress" type="System.String" allowAnonymous="true"/>
```

]

Comment: Ahmed, Great to know that this answer helped you. Please mark it as answer if this helped you.[ the right sign on left of the answer :)]